# why does the Collections utility class does not have a Iterator method in Java?

Tags: java, list, collections, iterator, set

The `Collections` utility class has `static methods` that operate on `collection`. For example,
`Collections.Sort(list)` that sorts the list.

why not a method of type

```
static <T> Iterator<T> iterator() { }
```

In this way, I could get an iterator over my collection as

```
Iterator it = Colletions.iterator(list)
```

The Collections do have `emptyIterator() and emptyListIterator()`, but I dont understand what purpose do they serve?

Comment: doesnt list.iterator() serve your purpose?

Comment: A better question is why doesn't List have a sort() method. And the answer is that in Java 8 it will.  Ideally you wouldn't need a Collections class in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a `Collections.iterator(Collection)` method, because the `Collection` interface has an `iterator()` method that returns an `Iterator` already.  It only makes sense when you have a `Collection` already, and the `Iterator` is coupled with the `Collection` anyway.  What would `Collections.iterator(Collection c)` do?  It would probably just call `return c.iterator();`.

I suppose that `Collections.emptyIterator()` and `Collections.emptyListIterator()` save the caller the processing to create an empty `Collection` / `List` just to call its `iterator()` / `listIterator()` method.

The [GRASP pattern "Information Expert"](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/25/grasp-patterns-information-expert-create-a-shopping-cart/) would indicate that the design of an `Iterator` would be with the class it iterates, because the class itself has the information needed to create an `Iterator`.

Comment: in this case, why does the `Collection interface` has `addAll` method and the `Collections` Class also has `addAll` method

Comment: It looks like they're slightly different.  `Collection#addAll` takes another `Collection` as an argument.  `Collections.addAll` takes a varargs parameter representing all elements to add to a `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need an iterator method because it's already defined in the [Collection Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html). It needs be so, because for different Collection classes the iterators can't work the same (internally) even if they provide the same functionality (externally).

[EDIT. Thanks, Marko.] Empty iterators allow you to write cleaner code, eliminating the need to cover special edge cases, and there's only *one way* to provide an empty iterator. Thus, it's defined in the Collections class with its predefined behavior.

Comment: The use of empty iterator should be quite obvious: it is the equivalent of an empty list, or more broadly, the "zero" element,  in the iterator space. It allows you to write cleaner code, eliminating the need to cover special edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

But we have [`Collection.iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator%28%29), that's exactly what you're looking for.

The `Collections` class contains a bunch of utility methods that are generic for all kinds of collections, whereas all the collections that implement the `Collection` interface contain specific implementations of a given functionality.

Because each `Collection` already has its own iterator, it doesn't make sense to have it as an utility method in `Collections`, besides it would be trivial to implement: just return the result of calling the `iterator()` method on the `Collection` received as parameter.

Comment: yes, I know there are alternatives, my questions why is not included in the Collections utility framework

Comment: @user1988876 ok, I expanded a bit more my explanation

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer only the "purpose of the empty iterator" part.

Consider this method:

```
boolean containsEvil(String x) {
  return x.contains("evil");
}
```

This method will fail for a null-argument, which is an edge case for it and it would need special handling to avoid the failure. However, if you take care in the rest of your program to never use `null` arguments and represent the concept of "no string" as an *empty string*, you don't need to handle the special case.

Occasionally you may also have an `Iterator`-based API:

```
boolean containsEvil(Iterator<String> xs) {
   while (xs.hasNext()) if (containsEvil(xs.next()) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Again, this will fail for a null-argument, so you will want to have an *empty iterator* factory around to stand for the "no iterator" case. In broader terms, you want your zero element in the iterator space, just as you want it in the string space.

Comment: Interesting. But aren't there null checks for that? if(arg!=null){/**/} ?

Comment: Yes, the null-checks are the "special handling" which I talk about, and the point of my answer is that you want to avoid them because they pollute the code with redundant, boilerplate, and distracting constructs.

Comment: So... are you suggesting avoid the fail-safe and instead use the empty list/iterator/strings in the rest of your code? If someone forgets or makes a mistake, that makes for a crashing program...

Comment: Yes, mistakes are paid by crashes. Better that than silent bugs.

Comment: Touché :) "Fail early and loudly". Point taken.